# How to show document from Firestore database in Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing a ToDo list in flutter. I created a Button to move the object to the done Todos but I don't know how I can show the Done Todos on that page. Here's my current code:

```
body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection("MoveTodos").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshots){

        if(snapshots.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();

        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshots.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshots.data.documents[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a Widget for each index, e.g. a `Text` widget which you pass the `DocumentSnapshot` and access some property on it.

```
String property = "someDocumentFieldName"

return ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: snapshots.data.documents.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshots.data.documents[index];
        return Text(documentSnapshot[property]);
}
```